# PyCharm - line numbers when exporting code to html

Tags: pycharm

I'm trying to export my python code (in PyCharm) to html with line numbers. Using "File > Export To Html" and selecting option: "Show line numbers".

Line numbers are provided but only against comment lines, not code. As below

I'm sure that I'm missing something simple, but can't find what?

```
    1    import pandas as pd
import csv
import os

current_file_path = __file__
current_file_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)


def test (input_text):
    """ 
2   This is a
3   test 
4   """

    #do something
    print(input_text)
    print("there are no line numbers here")
```

The code that I'm trying to export to html looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import os

current_file_path = __file__
current_file_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)


def test (input_text):
    """
    This is a
    test
    """

    #do something
    print(input_text)
    print("there are no line numbers here")
```

Comment: can you show the code snippet which you tried to export to html?

Comment: added to question

Comment: I copied the code you posted and exported to html. Line numbers are fine in my case.